# Crear una metaclase que crea clases inmutables

Tags: python, clase, diseño-de-clases

Sé que una metaclase es una clase cuyas instancias son clases. También sé que es posible modificar los atributos de la clase que se crea desde la metaclase. Lo que necesito es que una metaclase, en python, cree clases que, al instanciarlas, me permitan establecerle valores por defecto a sus propiedades (que puede ser mediante el constructor, o sea, que al menos el constructor de estas sea capaz de inicializar las propiedades), pero que una vez establecidas, las propiedades no puedan ser modificadas. Ya probé cambiando el `__setattr__` de las instancias en la propia metaclase, tanto en el `__new__` como en el `__init__`, y no funciona. He logrado que lance error cuando se intenta modificar una propiedad de estas clases con valor ya establecido, pero desearía no tener que lanzar error, que solo devolviera el valor que se le dio en la instanciación, el valor que le dio el constructor a la propiedad la primera vez. ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Lo que intento hacer es algo así:

```py
class Metaclase(type):
    def __new__(cls, nombre, bases, atributos):
        return super().__new__(cls, nombre, bases, atributos)
    
    def __init__(cls, nombre, bases, atributos):
        super().__init__(nombre, bases, atributos)
        # sobreescribir el setattr luego de inicializar para q no modifique los valores.
        cls.__setattr__ = lambda self, name, value: object.__setattr__(self, name, value) if hasattr(self, name) else None

# Crear una nueva clase usando nuestra metaclase
class MiClase(metaclass=Metaclase):
    def __init__(self, valor):
        self.valor = valor
```

Lo q necesito es q cuando haga:

````py
objeto = MiClase(100)  
print(objeto.valor)  # Imprime: 100
objeto.valor = 200 #  Error o:
print(objeto.valor) # Imprime: 100```
````

Comment: Voy a intentar responder, pero no logro entender muy bien tu pregunta. Tal vez si agregas un ejemplo de uso de una de las instancias de la metaclase, pueda entenderlo.

Comment: Ya lo edite. Le agregue un ejemplo a la descripcion del problema.

Comment: Gracias! Pregunta: por que una namedtuple (como dice la respuesta de más abajo) no sirve a tu proposito?

Comment: A ver, quizas pueda usar namedtuple, pero me gustaria mas poder hacerlo por mi cuenta para agregarle las caracteristicas q quiero y que se me ocurran en un futuro. Si no se puede esta bien, uso namedtuples, pero me gustaria, sobre todo no tener que importar una libreria para poder ejecutar mi programa... Y en parte tambien, por curiosidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En Python hay una clase como la que buscas. Se llama [`NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple). Por ejemplo:

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class Punto(NamedTuple):
    x: int
    y: int

p = Punto(1, 2)
p.x = 5 # Error 
print(p) # Punto(x=1, y=2)
```

Alguien en inglés se preguntó [cómo está implementada](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17916853/13419694).

También puedes ver [el código fuente](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/eebea7e515462b503632ada74923ec3246599c9c/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L355) de CPython.